# How to get this result with aggregate in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an invoice collection...

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"items" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "value" : 100,
        "price" : 9500
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "value" : 200,
        "price" : 9500
    }
],
"costs" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "price" : 100
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "price" : 150
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "price" : 250
    }
]}
```

I get Invoice amount with aggregate...

In other words =>

{$sum : {$multiply :{[$items.value, $items.price]} }} - {$sum : "$costs.price"};

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "amount" : 2849500
}
```

very thinks...

;-)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mongo  3.4 Version**

$map to multiply the item's price & value and $reduce to calculate the sum of item's price & value and $reduce to calculate the sum of cost's price. $subtract values from earlier reduce to get the final amount.

```
aggregate([{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        amount: {
            $subtract: [{
                $reduce: {
                    input: {
                        $map: {
                            input: "$items",
                            as: "item",
                            in: {
                                $multiply: ["$$item.value", "$$item.price"]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    initialValue: 0,
                    in: {
                        $add: ["$$value", "$$this"]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$costs.price",
                    initialValue: 0,
                    in: {
                        $add: ["$$value", "$$this"]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }

    }
}])
```

**Mongo 3.x Version**

First $project to multiply item's value & price. Next grouping to calculate the sum for both items and costs fields, which will result in one array value for each item and cost field and final project looks at only array value from both arrays with $arrayElemAt to subtract the values from each other.

```
aggregate(
    [{
        $project: {
            vpItems: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$items",
                    as: "item",
                    in: {
                        $multiply: ["$$item.value", "$$item.price"]
                    }
                }
            },
            costs: '$costs'
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            vpItems: {
                $addToSet: {
                    $sum: '$vpItems'
                }
            },
            pCosts: {
                $addToSet: {
                    $sum: '$costs.price'
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            amount: {
                $subtract: [{
                    $arrayElemAt: ["$vpItems", 0]
                }, {
                    $arrayElemAt: ["$pCosts", 0]
                }]
            }
        }
    }])
```

**Mongo 2.6 Version**

$unwind items and group to calcualte sum of values returned from multiply the item's price & value and $unwind costs to calculate the sum of item's price & value and project to $subtract values from previous grouping to calculate final amount.

```
aggregate([{
      $unwind: '$items'
  }, {
      $group: {
          _id: '$_id',
          totalItems: {
              $sum: {
                  $multiply: ["$items.value", "$items.price"]
              }
          },
          costs: {
              $first: '$costs'
          }
      }
  }, {
      $unwind: '$costs'
  }, {
      $group: {
          _id: '$_id',
          totalItems: {
              $first: '$totalItems'
          },
          totalPrice: {
              $sum: '$costs.price'
          }
      }
  }, {
      $project: {
          _id: 1,
          amount: {
              $subtract: ['$totalItems', '$totalPrice']
          }
      }
  }])
```

Comment: thanks my friend. but this error for $sum : "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$sum'",
"code" : 15999

Comment: I ran it on 3.2. What version of mongodb are you using ?

Comment: MongoDB version: 2.6.10

Comment: No, I can not. Sory

Comment: No worries. Give me some time. I'll find 2.6 complaint solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128730/discussion-between-mostafa-ghasemi-and-veeram).