# How to reduce to single document in finall stage of mongodb aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Document -** 
Document consists of Population data, Literate data.

```
    { 
    "_id" : NumberInt(0), 
    "area" : "India", 
    "population" : {
        "density" : NumberInt(382), 
        "class" : [
            {
                "rural" : [
                    {
                        "male" : [
                            NumberInt(61285192), 
                            NumberInt(427917052)
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "female" : [
                            NumberInt(56300322), 
                            NumberInt(405170610)
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "urban" : [
                    {
                        "male" : [
                            NumberInt(21666943), 
                            NumberInt(195807196)
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "female" : [
                            NumberInt(19536830), 
                            NumberInt(181298564)
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "education" : {
        "class" : [
            {
                "rural" : [
                    {
                        "male" : NumberInt(288047480)
                    }, 
                    {
                        "female" : NumberInt(204973398)
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "urban" : [
                    {
                        "male" : NumberInt(204973398)
                    }, 
                    {
                        "female" : NumberInt(129276960)
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Aggregation Query -** 
Trying to figure out the nodejs query which will help to create single document (JSON) containing information about id, area, density, male data and female data.
Below query is generating two documents. How to merge two documents into single document

```
router.get('/population/:id', function (req, res, next) {
        var id = Number(req.params.id);
        sCollection.aggregate(
            {
                $match: { _id: id }
            },
            {
                $unwind: '$population.class'
            },
            {
                $unwind: '$population.class.rural'
            },
            {
                $project: { _id: '$_id', area: '$area', density: '$population.density', ruralMale: '$population.class.rural.male', ruralFemale: '$population.class.rural.female' }
            },
           ).toArray(function (err, population) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send('Error census-population not found  ' + err);
                } else {

                    res.json(population);
                }
            });
    });
```

[image: Overall Aggregation Flow -]
Attached image will help in better understanding of the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40732823/2683814 See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use $group like this:

```
[ 
   {$match: { _id: 0 }},
   {$unwind: '$population.class'},
   {$unwind: '$population.class.rural'},  
   {$group:{_id:"$_id", area: {$first: "$area"}, density: {$first:'$population.density'}, ruralMale: {$first: '$population.class.rural.male'}, ruralFemale: {$last:'$population.class.rural.female' }}}
```

]